# Laravel Select Only Child table data and ignore parent data

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys I wanna select from child of child data and I don't need parent data can you please help me?

Team Table
Id, Name, manager_id

Manager Table
id company_id, user_id

Team Modal

```
public function manager()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Manager::class);
}
```

Manager Modal

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Controller

```
managerUsers = Team::with('manager.user')
        ->where('company_id', $company->id)
        ->get();
```

it works fine but it also return team and manager table data I want only user table data

Comment: Try `->pluck()`

Comment: pluck is not handy here

Comment: This is much easier `Team::with('manager.user')->where('company_id', $company->id)->select(['users.id', 'users.email'])->get();` you can select any other column like this way,  you need to select the `users.id `  this is required

Comment: I',m not sure but this may also works `Team::with('manager.user')->where('company_id', $company->id)->get(['users.id', 'users.name']);`

Comment: Also try this `Team::with('manager.user')->where('company_id', $company->id)->get(['users.*']);`

Answer (score 2):

I didnt test this but it should work for you

Here is the documentation for [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

This will find managers who has teams with specific company id

```php
$managerUsers = Manager::whereHas('team', function($query) use ($company) {
    $query->where('company_id', $company->id);
})->with('user')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$managerUsers = Team::query()
        ->join('managers', 'managers.id', '=', 'teams.manager_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'managers.user_id')
        ->select(['users.id','users.first_name', 'users.last_name'])
        ->get();
```